# Is there an Android IAB(in-app billing) signature verification library implemented in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, in-app-billing

Server implemented node.js, So I want to IAB in an server instance. But cann't find IAB library for node.js.

So, Just do porting Java to Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I make simple library base on express, this library porting php to javascript.

attach link below

https://github.com/nothing2lose/node-InAppBilling